# mach_star framework XCode linking problems

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to build the DisposeWindow+Beep_Injector example project here: https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star and am having trouble getting the framework it comes bundled with(`mach_inject_bundle`) linked to the application project correctly.

Here's the error I get:

```
Ld build/Development/DisposeWindow+Beep.bundle/Contents/MacOS/DisposeWindow+Beep normal x86_64
    cd /Users/me/repos/mach_star/DisposeWindow+Beep
    /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -bundle -L/Users/me/repos/mach_star/DisposeWindow+Beep/build/Development -F/Users/me/repos/mach_star/DisposeWindow+Beep/build/Development -filelist /Users/me/repos/mach_star/DisposeWindow+Beep/build/DisposeWindow+Beep.build/Development/DisposeWindow+Beep.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DisposeWindow+Beep.LinkFileList -framework Carbon -framework AudioToolbox -o /Users/me/repos/mach_star/DisposeWindow+Beep/build/Development/DisposeWindow+Beep.bundle/Contents/MacOS/DisposeWindow+Beep

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mach_override", referenced from:
      _load in DisposeWindow+Beep.o
     (maybe you meant: _mach_override_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All the individual projects build fine but I can't build the parent project...

Here's a screenshot of what all the configs look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t1LK.png

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to build it in 32 bit instead of 64 bit?

Comment: Last entry in the version history is from Sun Dec 18 2005 (quite old)and there it is said that XCode 2.2 is recommended. Can you get XCode 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mach_override, there is only a mach_override_ptr. You have to use that function.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the symbol table says but the examples use mach_override and I assume they compiled at some point...

Comment: Haha, alright, that's what my inclination was but I was hoping someone had run across that and fixed mach_override. I'll give mach_override_ptr a shot. Thanks.